# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los section's salgan uno al lado de otro y alineados?

Tags: html, css

Estoy en proceso de intentar construir un formulario de registro según nuestra necesidad. Mi problema es que los *section* que tengo creado visualmente se me ven mal. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o guía que puedan entregarme, básicamente lo que estoy intentando hacer es que no se vean desalineados los *section* del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi código:

```css
/* Estilos generales */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}



form {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  color: #333333;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
}

/* Estilos para dispositivos móviles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  section {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Vendors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Creation New Vendors</h1>

    <section>
      <form>
        <h2> Request General Information</h2>
        <label for="person">Requestor:</label>
        <input type="text" id="person" name="person" required><br><br>

        <label for="date">Date of request:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required><br><br>

        <label for="company">Choose Company:</label>
        <select id="company" name="company">
          <option value="eduLLC">Austral Edu LLC</option>
          <option value="servicesLLC">Austral Services LLC</option>
          <option value="australCL">Austral Turismo Brasil Ltda</option>
          <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Chile Spa</option>
          <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Peru SRL</option>
        </select>

        <label for="vendor">Supplier's Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendor" name="vendor" required><br><br>

        <label for="currency">Choose currency:</label>
        <select id="currency" name="currency" required>
          <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real (BRL)</option>
          <option value="CAD">Dólar canadiense (CAD)</option>
          <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso (CLP)</option>
          <option value="COP">Colombian Peso (COP)</option>
          <option value="CRC">Costa Rica Colon (CRC)</option>
          <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna (CZK)</option>
          <option value="DKK">Danish Krone (DKK)</option>
          <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
          <option value="GBP">Libra esterlina (GBP)</option>
          <option value="USD">Dólar estadounidense (USD)</option>
          <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option>
          <option value="PEN">Peruvian Peso (PEN)</option>
        </select>   
      </form>
    </section>  

    <section>
      <form>
        <h2> Vendor General Information</h2>
        <label for="vendorLegalName">Vendor Legal Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorLegalName" name="vendorLegalName" required><br><br>

        <label for="vendorAddress">Vendor Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorAddress" name="vendorAddress"><br><br>

        <label for="vendorPhoneNumber">Vendor Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorPhoneNumber" name="vendorPhoneNumber"><br><br>

        <label for="vendorEmail">Vendor Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorEmail" name="vendorEmail" required><br><br>

        <label for="vendorServices">Vendor Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorServices" name="vendorServices" ><br><br>

      </form>
    </section>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a Stackoverflow, podrías adjuntarnos tu código completo? Incluyendo el HTML y CSS, recuerda hacer un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Lo intenté, pero cada vez que queria enviarlo, me decia que mi pregunta era solo código y no me dejaba mandarlo, me ayudas con eso tambien si no es mucha molestia?

Comment: Puedes crear un proyecto en https://codepen.io/ y compartirnos el enlace.

Comment: Creo que este es el enlace

https://codepen.io/AxeLedesma/pen/poOOaaE

Comment: Perfecto, moví el código en tu pregunta, por si el link se cae

Comment: Pegué lo que modificaste, pero sigo viendo el form de la misma forma, no sé que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solamente tendrías que usar la propiedad `vertical-align: top;` para que el `section` esté alineado arriba del todo:

```
section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Demo:

```css
/* Estilos generales */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40%;
}



form {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  color: #333333;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
}

/* Estilos para dispositivos móviles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  section {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Vendors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Creation New Vendors</h1>

    <section>
      <form>
        <h2> Request General Information</h2>
        <label for="person">Requestor:</label>
        <input type="text" id="person" name="person" required><br><br>

        <label for="date">Date of request:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required><br><br>

        <label for="company">Choose Company:</label>
        <select id="company" name="company">
          <option value="eduLLC">Austral Edu LLC</option>
          <option value="servicesLLC">Austral Services LLC</option>
          <option value="australCL">Austral Turismo Brasil Ltda</option>
          <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Chile Spa</option>
          <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Peru SRL</option>
        </select>

        <label for="vendor">Supplier's Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendor" name="vendor" required><br><br>

        <label for="currency">Choose currency:</label>
        <select id="currency" name="currency" required>
          <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real (BRL)</option>
          <option value="CAD">Dólar canadiense (CAD)</option>
          <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso (CLP)</option>
          <option value="COP">Colombian Peso (COP)</option>
          <option value="CRC">Costa Rica Colon (CRC)</option>
          <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna (CZK)</option>
          <option value="DKK">Danish Krone (DKK)</option>
          <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
          <option value="GBP">Libra esterlina (GBP)</option>
          <option value="USD">Dólar estadounidense (USD)</option>
          <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option>
          <option value="PEN">Peruvian Peso (PEN)</option>
        </select>   
      </form>
    </section>  

    <section>
      <form>
        <h2> Vendor General Information</h2>
        <label for="vendorLegalName">Vendor Legal Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorLegalName" name="vendorLegalName" required><br><br>

        <label for="vendorAddress">Vendor Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorAddress" name="vendorAddress"><br><br>

        <label for="vendorPhoneNumber">Vendor Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorPhoneNumber" name="vendorPhoneNumber"><br><br>

        <label for="vendorEmail">Vendor Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorEmail" name="vendorEmail" required><br><br>

        <label for="vendorServices">Vendor Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorServices" name="vendorServices" ><br><br>

      </form>
    </section>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">


  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**:

Para evitar que se desborde los `section`, la idea sería que los `section` ocupen todo el alto posible (el `100%`). Entonces, primero estructuremos tu HTML. Vamos a crear un `div` que encierre a estos dos `section` y a tu `input` enviar.

```
<div class="contenido">
  <section>
    <!-- Todo tu section 1 -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <!-- Todo tu section 2 -->
  </section>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</div>
```

Y a la clase `contenido` indiquemos que sea flexible, para que los `section` junto con tu botón de enviar estén uno al lado del otro:

```
.contenido {
  display: flex;
}
```

Y hagamos que los `form` de los `section` ocupen toda la altura posible de `contenido`, ya que cada `form` está dentro de un `section`. De esta forma, la altura del `form` será el mismo que el `section`, y como `section` está dentro de `contenido`, hará que éste ocupe toda la altura posible (y ya no vendría necesario el `vertical-align: top` del `section`):

```
form {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%; /* le añado esto */
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Ahora, debemos modificar a tu `input` enviar, ya que, debido a que el `input` no está encerrado en ningún bloque, la altura del `input` ocupará todo el máximo de `contenido` automáticamente (al igual que los `sections`). Entonces, creemos un `div` que encierre a este `input`:

```
<div class="contenido">
  <section>
    <!-- Todo tu section 1 -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <!-- Todo tu section 2 -->
  </section>
  <div class="myinput">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Y le damos las siguientes clases, para centrar su contenido (tu `input`):

```
.myinput {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Así, el `div` llamado `myinput` ocupará todo el alto, pero el `input` no, solo estará centrado.

Y por último, para que se vea mejor en dispositivos pequeños, hice las siguientes modificaciones en la regla `@media`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .contenido, section {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 20px;
  }

  .myinput {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Aquí solo indico que la dirección de los elementos que están dentro de `contenido` y `section` serán en columnas, tendrán un ancho de `100%` y una separación de `20px`. También, el `div` del input ocuará todo el ancho de `100%` para que se centre correctamente.

---

Código final:

```css
/* Estilos generales */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

.contenido {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

.myinput {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  color: #333333;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
}

/* Estilos para dispositivos móviles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .contenido, section {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 20px;
  }

  .myinput {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Vendors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Creation New Vendors</h1>

    <div class="contenido">
      <section>
        <form>
          <h2> Request General Information</h2>
          <label for="person">Requestor:</label>
          <input type="text" id="person" name="person" required><br><br>

          <label for="date">Date of request:</label>
          <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required><br><br>

          <label for="company">Choose Company:</label>
          <select id="company" name="company">
            <option value="eduLLC">Austral Edu LLC</option>
            <option value="servicesLLC">Austral Services LLC</option>
            <option value="australCL">Austral Turismo Brasil Ltda</option>
            <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Chile Spa</option>
            <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Peru SRL</option>
          </select>

          <label for="vendor">Supplier's Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="vendor" name="vendor" required><br><br>

          <label for="currency">Choose currency:</label>
          <select id="currency" name="currency" required>
            <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real (BRL)</option>
            <option value="CAD">Dólar canadiense (CAD)</option>
            <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso (CLP)</option>
            <option value="COP">Colombian Peso (COP)</option>
            <option value="CRC">Costa Rica Colon (CRC)</option>
            <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna (CZK)</option>
            <option value="DKK">Danish Krone (DKK)</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
            <option value="GBP">Libra esterlina (GBP)</option>
            <option value="USD">Dólar estadounidense (USD)</option>
            <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option>
            <option value="PEN">Peruvian Peso (PEN)</option>
          </select>   
        </form>
      </section>  

      <section>
        <form>
          <h2> Vendor General Information</h2>
          <label for="vendorLegalName">Vendor Legal Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="vendorLegalName" name="vendorLegalName" required><br><br>

          <label for="vendorAddress">Vendor Address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="vendorAddress" name="vendorAddress"><br><br>

          <label for="vendorPhoneNumber">Vendor Phone:</label>
          <input type="text" id="vendorPhoneNumber" name="vendorPhoneNumber"><br><br>

          <label for="vendorEmail">Vendor Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="vendorEmail" name="vendorEmail" required><br><br>

          <label for="vendorServices">Vendor Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="vendorServices" name="vendorServices" ><br><br>

        </form>
      </section>
      <div class="myinput">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**éste enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/xxywRVN).

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió para que quede visualmente por arriba, pero ahora se desalinea abajo T_T

Comment: Ah ok, entiendo...

Comment: @AxelLedesma Acabo de modificar mi respuesta, me avisa si esto es lo que deseas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, solamente una duda a pesar de que resolviste toda mi duda.
El botón para que se vea abajo en vez de al lado, que tendría que modificar ?

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta, olvidé centrar el botón

Answer (score 0):

Para el posicionamiento de una caja al lado de otra utilizaremos [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display), en este caso te muestro tres formas de poder realizar este posicionamiento:

### Utilizando **`inline-block`**:

Para este caso utilizaremos **`display: inline-block`** para poder posicionar el objeto al lado del otro y **`vertical-align: top`** para que alineen en la parte superior uno del otro.

```css
section > div {
    background: #006699;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>Contenido A</div>
    <div>Contenido B</div>
</section>
```

### Utilizando **`table-cell`**:

De esta forma se simula una alineación de tabla al utilizar **`display: table-cell`**.

```css
section > div {
    background: #006699;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;

    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>Contenido A</div>
    <div>Contenido B</div>
</section>
```

### Utilizando **`flex`**:

En este caso utilizamos **`display: flex;`** en el contenedor y no así en los objetos que queremos alinear, y también utilizaremos **`justify-content: center;`** para poder centrar los objetos.

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
section > div {
    background: #006699;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>Contenido A</div>
    <div>Contenido B</div>
</section>
```

### Para tu caso en especifico:

En tu caso agregué **`vertical-align: top`** porque estas usando el primer ejemplo que puse, el otro cambio que realicé es en el form donde el porcentaje estaba muy pequeño siendo que el padre esta a un 40% los hijos deben estar a un 100% en este caso para poder ocupar el máximo.

```css
/* Estilos generales */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #333333;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40%;
}
form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  color: #333333;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
}

/* Estilos para dispositivos móviles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  section {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Vendors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Creation New Vendors</h1>

    <section>
      <form>
        <h2> Request General Information</h2>
        <label for="person">Requestor:</label>
        <input type="text" id="person" name="person" required><br><br>

        <label for="date">Date of request:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required><br><br>

        <label for="company">Choose Company:</label>
        <select id="company" name="company">
          <option value="eduLLC">Austral Edu LLC</option>
          <option value="servicesLLC">Austral Services LLC</option>
          <option value="australCL">Austral Turismo Brasil Ltda</option>
          <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Chile Spa</option>
          <option value="australBR">Servicios Austral Peru SRL</option>
        </select>

        <label for="vendor">Supplier's Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendor" name="vendor" required><br><br>

        <label for="currency">Choose currency:</label>
        <select id="currency" name="currency" required>
          <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real (BRL)</option>
          <option value="CAD">Dólar canadiense (CAD)</option>
          <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso (CLP)</option>
          <option value="COP">Colombian Peso (COP)</option>
          <option value="CRC">Costa Rica Colon (CRC)</option>
          <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna (CZK)</option>
          <option value="DKK">Danish Krone (DKK)</option>
          <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
          <option value="GBP">Libra esterlina (GBP)</option>
          <option value="USD">Dólar estadounidense (USD)</option>
          <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option>
          <option value="PEN">Peruvian Peso (PEN)</option>
        </select>   
      </form>
    </section>  

    <section>
      <form>
        <h2> Vendor General Information</h2>
        <label for="vendorLegalName">Vendor Legal Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorLegalName" name="vendorLegalName" required><br><br>

        <label for="vendorAddress">Vendor Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorAddress" name="vendorAddress"><br><br>

        <label for="vendorPhoneNumber">Vendor Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorPhoneNumber" name="vendorPhoneNumber"><br><br>

        <label for="vendorEmail">Vendor Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorEmail" name="vendorEmail" required><br><br>

        <label for="vendorServices">Vendor Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorServices" name="vendorServices" ><br><br>

      </form>
    </section>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">


  </body>
</html>
```

Se vería de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]